# Set background image in html body using python flask framework

Tags: python, html, css, flask

How to set html body background image 
my images is inside FlasApp-->static-->in static there are two folders(css and images)-->
**In .css file used the below code:**

```
body  {
    background: url("images/background.jpg");
}
```

**In .html file used the below code:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/main.css') }}">
```

But neither background color is shown nor background image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try it

```
body  {
    background-image: url({{ url_for('static', filename='images/background.jpg') }})
}
```

but i think that this always will work, because you forgot to put `/static/` in front of `images/background.jpg`, and it need to be `background-image` not only `background`

```
body  {
    background-image: url("/static/images/background.jpg");
}
```

Comment: Thanks @zimdero body  {
    background-image: url("/static/images/background.jpg");
} will work.